# PHP 404 handling

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

All requests go through index.php, and if content was not found I do:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
exit;
```

and expect to see contents of `/404` as defined in `.htaccess`: `ErrorDocument 404 /404`

The problem is that I see a blank page on Chrome and Firefox, but on IE see its 404 page (not mine, browsers 404 page).

Sending header is not enough to handle redirect, so it's expected to be done by `.htaccess,` but fails. Should I redirect it whith PHP like so:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header("Location: " . $dirpath . "404");
```

Comment: Sounds like your `/404` is a 404 and therefore your 404 is 404ing.

Comment: No, you don't need to send a Location, that will not produce a correct 404 result. I don't think that you can set ErrorDocument to a folder, it need to be an actual file to execute. /404/index.php, for example.

Comment: It's not a folder, all my requests are .htaccessed to index.php and urls are rewriten. Anyway setting it to `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` gives same result as described in question

Comment: Use ErrorDocument 404 /index.php and then within index.php you need to handle paths that don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `ErrorDocument 404` won't work on your way out from PHP. That is only applicable when Apache detects 404 for an incoming request and ends up invoking `ErrorDocument 404` handler.

Once control is handed over to PHP as normal request processor Apache just returns output returned by PHP module to a requesting client.

Only thing you can do is this:

```
require_once("404.php"); // include 404 handler
exit;
```

And inside `404.php` you can do:

```
http_response_code(404); // sends 404 status to browser
```

Comment: Read first sentence of my answer :)

Comment: But I do `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([^\.]+))\.pl [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.pl%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: that rule is for `www` removal and has nothing to do with `ErrorDocument`

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

Comment: Ok that rule is just sending every request to `/index.php`

Comment: Is that the flaw was pointed? Any indea to make it proper way?

Comment: As I explained `ErrorDocument` isn't invoked on your way put from PHP to browser. I have already provided work around in my question.

Comment: Are they any other downsides than URL change here?

Comment: If you send a Location redirect, the user is going to actually get a 302 and then 200 response code rather than a 404. This may be okay, but will also mean that search engines won't be able to tell valid paths from invalid ones, if that is a concern for you.

Comment: After applaying solution page sends first `200` http_response_code and after applaying `http_response_code(404)`  it returns `404`. Is that solely for search engines?

Comment: Yes 404 for SEO purpose only so that wrong URLs aren't cached

Comment: Thats totally what I wanted.